# AttributeError: 'Block' object has no attribute 'sender

Tags: python

I am trying to create my own blockchain using python.

I took [this source code](https://github.com/oalsing/Simple-Blockchain/tree/master/src) and I am trying to tweak it to fit what I need.
My code:

```
import datetime
import hashlib


class Block:
    def __init__(
            self,
            previous_block_hash,
            data,
            timestamp,
            sender,
    ):
        self.previous_block_hash = previous_block_hash
        self.data = data
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.hash = self.get_hash()
        self.sender = self.get_sender()

    @staticmethod
    def create_genesis_block():
        return Block('0', '0', datetime.datetime.now(), '')

    def get_sender(self):
        self.sender = input('Enter senders ID number: ')
        return self.sender

    def get_hash(self):
        header_bin = str(self.previous_block_hash) + str(self.data) \
                     + str(self.timestamp) + str(self.sender)

        inner_hash = \
            hashlib.sha256(header_bin.encode()).hexdigest().encode()
        outer_hash = hashlib.sha256(inner_hash).hexdigest()
        return outer_hash


blockchain = [Block.create_genesis_block()]
length_of_blockchain = len(blockchain)

print ('The genesis block has been created.')
print ('Hash: %s' % blockchain[0].hash)

blockchain.append(Block(blockchain[length_of_blockchain - 1].hash,
                        'Blockchain Number: '[length_of_blockchain - 1],
                        datetime.datetime.now(), Block.get_sender()))
```

I want to add a sender and receiver to the Block. So, I started out with one first and that is the sender. I keep getting this error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydCcc.png) and I am not sure how to fix it. Everything is being tested locally to make sure everything checks out then I will add react native to it. Hoping someone can help me

Comment: Although you go into detail about your issue, it is not a good practice to link to other websites as links can become broken. Please take a moment to either provide a [MCVE] or post your code directly using [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Please see the formatting link about formatting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access `self.sender` before initializing it. Reordering initialization might help us here.

```
import datetime
import hashlib


class Block:
    def __init__(
            self,
            previous_block_hash,
            data,
            timestamp,
            sender,
    ):
        self.previous_block_hash = previous_block_hash
        self.data = data
        self.timestamp = timestamp

        #reordering self.hash and self.sender as self.get_sender() references to self.sender
        self.sender = self.get_sender()
        self.hash = self.get_hash()

    @staticmethod
    def create_genesis_block():
        return Block('0', '0', datetime.datetime.now(), '')

    def get_sender(self):
        self.sender = input('Enter senders ID number: ')
        return self.sender

    def get_hash(self):
        header_bin = str(self.previous_block_hash) + str(self.data) \
            + str(self.timestamp) + str(self.sender)

        inner_hash = \
            hashlib.sha256(header_bin.encode()).hexdigest().encode()
        outer_hash = hashlib.sha256(inner_hash).hexdigest()
        return outer_hash
```

hope this helps